# TypeScript template literal type parsing error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to make `type test` become a union of the enum `ModalTypes`' values. According to the docs I should be able to write a `type test` like in the commented row. It seems to yield the correct type that I want, but it's giving me a compile error. If I write the union manually as shown in this picture, everything works as expected. What am I missing?
[image: Code snippet]

Here is the error that I get `Parsing error: Type expected`. Although I don't get any squigglies in the code.
[image: Error]

You can clearly see that test is becoming the string type union that I'm aiming for. But it's giving me the error above.
[image: Code snippet]

Same code, in text...

```ts
export enum ModalTypes {
   USER = 'user',
   NOTE = 'note',
   REMINDER = 'reminder',
   CONTRACT = 'contract',
}

type test = `${ModalTypes}`;
// type test = 'user' | 'note' | 'reminder' | 'contract';
type req = {
    [key in test]: {
        try: string;
    };
};
```

Comment: Where is that error produced? Are you using a TypeScript compiler version different from what VS Code is set to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, why not use something like:

```js
// 'USER' | 'NOTE' | ...
type Key = keyof typeof ModalTypes;
// basically an alias for ModalTypes
type Value = (typeof ModalTypes)[Key];
```

It's worth mentioning that your `ModalTypes` "type" already represents the union of your enum values. Therefore `Value` is basically a convoluted alias for `ModalTypes`. That your enum type is already an union of its values can be seen here:

```js
type Omitted = Exclude<Value, 'user'>;
// Mousing over the above gives the following hint in VS Code:
type Omitted = ModalTypes.NOTE | ModalTypes.REMINDER | ModalTypes.CONTRACT
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realise that I could use ModalTypes immediately. Perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that it's some wrong settings in your linter.

Also, you can write this `req` type with usage of `Record`.

```js
type req = Record<ModalTypes, { try: string }>
```